# How to ensure JPEG image is valid and can be handled by PHP?

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick, gd, laravel

I have this JPEG that has been giving problems to the function `imagesx($this->image)` from the [Resizer library](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/resizer) that I am using. I am able to view the image using the browser, and when attempting to resize, I get the error:

```
imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

It is OK for me to not handle this file if it is going to throw an error. How can I use PHP to check whether this image can be handled properly by PHP's image functions?

---

**Code that calls the Library**

```
// Download the photo
$img_content = file_get_contents($url);
if($img_content !== FALSE) {
    file_put_contents($img_documentroot . $img_subpath . $img_filename . '_tmp.jpg',
     $img_content);
}

echo $url . '<br>';
echo $img_documentroot . $img_subpath . $img_filename . '_tmp.jpg<br>';
ob_flush();
flush();

// Resize photo
Resizer::open( $img_documentroot . $img_subpath . $img_filename . '_tmp.jpg' )
->resize(300, 300, 'landscape' )
->save($img_documentroot . $img_subpath . $img_filename . '.jpg' , 90 );

// Thumbnail photo
Resizer::open( $img_documentroot . $img_subpath . $img_filename . '_tmp.jpg' )
->resize(100, 100, 'crop' )
->save($img_documentroot . $img_subpath . $img_filename . '.jpg' , 90 );
```

---

**Output**

I also echoed out the full path of the image being resized.

```
http://www.ApartmentsInAllstonMA.com/Images/Apts/132847_kn1.jpg
/home/photos/public_html/2012/0917/2516539_7_tmp.jpg
resource(127) of type (gd)
resource(130) of type (gd)
http://www.ApartmentsInMedford.com/Images/Apts/132847_lv2.jpg
/home/photos/public_html/2012/0917/2516539_11_tmp.jpg
resource(163) of type (gd)
resource(166) of type (gd)
http://www.AllstonApartmentX.com/images/agents/61.jpg
/home/photos/public_html/2012/0917/2516539_12_tmp.jpg
bool(false)
```

---

### UPDATE

This is the code snippet that is causing the library to return a `false` value.

```
private function open_image( $file )
{

    // If $file isn't an array, we'll turn it into one
    if ( !is_array($file) ) {
        $file = array(
            'type'      => File::mime( strtolower(File::extension($file)) ),
            'tmp_name'  => $file
        );
    }

    $mime = $file['type'];
    $file_path = $file['tmp_name'];

    switch ( $mime )
    {
        case 'image/pjpeg': // IE6
        case File::mime('jpg'): $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg( $file_path );  break;
        case File::mime('gif'): $img = @imagecreatefromgif( $file_path );   break;
        case File::mime('png'): $img = @imagecreatefrompng( $file_path );   break;
        default:                $img = false;                               break;
    }

    return $img;
}
```

Comment: You are passing something wrong to the library you are using or the library you are using is broken internally. The error clearly says what the error is, a wrong parameter type. You might want to reconsider changing the library or show us the code you use to call the actual function.

Comment: It sounds like `$this->image` is a boolean, when it should be an image resource. Try doing a `var_dump($this->image)` and see what comes out.

Comment: I did a var_dump($this->image) on a set of images. For the proper images, I get something like `resource(64) of type (gd)`, but for the image giving an error, I get `bool(false)`. This image does exist, and I can access it using the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for the mime type is a very good method to ensure the validity of JPEG image. Here is how you can do this.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type
$type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";  
if($type == "image/jpeg") { 
     //Valid JPEG Image
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

According to your errors, you *are sending **boolean** value instead of image resource*.

Comment: Will checking the mime type help to ensure I'm not sending a boolean value? I am guessing its sending a `false` boolean value because the file is not a valid image.

Comment: Will using `is_resource()` to check for this bad image help? I am thinking of checking for image that returns a bool `false` and ignoring it

Comment: @Nyxynyx, Check the validity of the image first, then only continue further processing.

Comment: `is_resource()` does not work, I'm trying to enable `finfo()` on the server now.

Answer (score 1):

The file might have the .JPG extension, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's the right file type.  I have seen users take a .PNG file and rename it to .JPG before, thinking they could convert between formats that way.

It also might be a valid JPEG file that uses a CMYK colorspace instead of an RGB one.  Every once in a while I see one of those - usually from a print designer.  I usually check these by opening them in Photoshop and looking under Image -> Mode to see whether it says RGB or CMYK.  In Windows, you also may be able to determine the colorspace by right-clicking, selecting Properties, and then looking under the Advanced tab.